Can we expose organization metrics in AzureDevOps to a Dashboard
I want to be able to see the amount of agents that are used (daily,weekly,monthly) as well as the jobs, currently running and the queued ones.
That is visible from the organization settings, however is there a way to expose those metrics in a Dashboard inside an 'Admin' project.
I saw that there is a way to expose those metrics in Grafana, via node exporter:
https://github.com/webdevops/azure-devops-exporter
But i would prefer not to use third-party code.


I want to be able to see the amount of agents that are used (daily,weekly,monthly) as well as the jobs, currently running and the queued ones. That is visible from the organization settings, however is there a way to expose those metrics in a Dashboard inside an 'Admin' project.

The metric you referred should be the Pool consumption report which exists on organization and project level agent pool.
It uses the Azure DevOps Analytics service and the TaskAgentRequestSnapshots endpoint. You can query this endpoint using the following URL prefix:
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project_id}/_odata/v4.0-preview/TaskAgentRequestSnapshots.
But it's not supported to expose it in Dashboard currently.
If you would like it in DevOps in future, you can raise a feature request in community link, thanks.
